# PHP app: Dealing with potential security issues with your database credentials

Tags: php

Is it enough to wrap your database credentials (and any other sensitive information) inside a public method of a PHP class?

I have always been leery of this, so I have a config.ini file OUTSIDE of the public_html directory, and use PHP's `parse_ini_file` for the few times I need access to that sensitive information, so that there is no way it is accessible anywhere in the app without parsing that file.

However, I pretty much every app or platform I've ever used uses a simple config.php file to store it all in, and just uses it from there.

Am I over thinking is? Are there any potential risks/benefits of one method over another?

My method:

config.ini (outside public_html):

```
host = 'localhost'
database = 'db_name'
user = 'db_user'
pass = 'db_pass'
```

Inside a class included with each page:

```
public function get_settings() {

  static $ini;

  if ($ini) {

    $ini = parse_ini_file(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config.ini', true);
    return $ini;

  } else {

    return $ini;

  }
}
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that the config.ini won't be accessible (most likely) for writing/changing from web-code (or PHP), there isn't really any benefit to doing it like this. To change the config, for instance, you will have to manually edit the file (makes for problematic reconfig if this code is used on servers where you don't have full control). Also, on shared servers, you might not have access to a file-area outside the root of the webhost. Also, if there are hackers, they wouldn't really struggle to get access to the file regardless - access from within PHP is mostly the same.

Comment: There definitely are risks if you have your .ini in public_html without any protection whatsoever.  You're not overthinking this!  One way to protet your .ini (if you can) is have it outside of public_html.  If you can't, another way is to have inside public_html but have a suitable directive in `.htaccess` to stop requests (forbidden!).  Many apps do that.  I often do this for an entire directory, such as `app-private` and put all private stuff like .ini files in that directory within public_html.  Whatever you do, DO NOT store passwords in code and then save it on github.com!